# How to use axios in Effect Hook?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

In class based Component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => {
        this.setState({
            posts: res.data.slice(0, 10)
        });
        console.log(posts);
    })
}
```

I tried this:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => {
        setPosts(res.data.slice(0, 10));
        console.log(posts);
    })
});
```

It creates an infinite loop. If I pass a []/{} as the second argument[1][2], then it blocks further call. But it also prevents the array from updating.

[1] [Infinite loop in useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect)

[2] [How to call loading function with React useEffect only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once)

Comment: What do you mean by "If I pass a `[]`/`{}` as the second argument, then it blocks further call". That is what you want to do to only run the function given to `useEffect` after the initial render.

Comment: Yes. I want to run the function once as it's updating posts array again and again. After following the approach you mentioned in other post I got the expected "run useEffect once", but my posts array is still empty. Isn't it supposed to be [post1, post2, ...].

Comment: [It should work to give an empty array as the second argument](https://codesandbox.io/s/0oq7z37v0w).

Comment: @Tholle I have tried this already. `setPosts(res.data.slice(0, 10)); console.log(posts);` Output: `Array []`.

Comment: Yes, `console.log(posts);` will be an empty array because of how closures work in JavaScript, but if you use `posts` in your rendering, it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. https://codesandbox.io/s/w0xx6zl5wk?module=%2Fsrc%2FHome.js

Comment: @Tholle I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Giving an empty array as second argument to `useEffect` to indicate that you only want the effect to run once after the initial render is the way to go. The reason why `console.log(posts);` is showing you an empty array is because the `posts` variable is still referring to the initial array, and `setPosts` is also asynchronous, but it will still work as you want if used in the rendering.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPosts([{ id: 0, content: "foo" }, { id: 1, content: "bar" }]);
      console.log(posts);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>{posts.map(post => <div key={post.id}>{post.content}</div>)}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check how [axios-hooks](https://github.com/simoneb/axios-hooks) is implemented.

It's super simple and uses the config object (or url) you provide to decide when to make a request, and when not to, as explained in [Tholle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53153948/32093).

In addition to allowing you to use the awesome axios in your stateless functional components, it also supports server side rendering, which - it turns out - hooks make very straightforward to implement.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that package.

Comment: The package is awesome! although I wonder how to not send request when useAxios is called for the first time ? since you will never POST something before you submit the form.

Comment: @Min it's not currently supported but it would be hopefully simple to implement. Would you create an issue on the project github page? PRs welcome too :)

Answer (score 2):

I've written a [Custom Hooks](https://github.com/use-hooks/react-hooks-axios) for Axios.js.

Here's an example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import useAxios from '@use-hooks/axios';

export default function App() {
  const [gender, setGender] = useState('');
  const {
    response,
    loading,
    error,
    query,
  } = useAxios({
    url: `https://randomuser.me/api/${gender === 'unknow' ? 'unknow' : ''}`,
    method: 'GET',
    options: {
      params: { gender },
    },
    trigger: gender,
    filter: () => !!gender,
  });

  const { data } = response || {};

  const options = [
    { gender: 'female', title: 'Female' },
    { gender: 'male', title: 'Male' },
    { gender: 'unknow', title: 'Unknow' },
  ];

  if (loading) return 'loading...';
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>DEMO of <span style={{ color: '#F44336' }}>@use-hooks/axios</span></h2>
      {options.map(item => (
        <div key={item.gender}>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id={item.gender}
            value={item.gender}
            checked={gender === item.gender}
            onChange={e => setGender(e.target.value)}
          />
          {item.title}
        </div>
      ))}
      <button type="button" onClick={query}>Refresh</button>
      <div>
        {error ? error.message || 'error' : (
          <textarea cols="100" rows="30" defaultValue={JSON.stringify(data || {}, '', 2)} />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see the result [online](https://use-hooks.github.io/react-hooks-axios/).