# State update in event listener react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I create simple custom hook that save the screen height and width .
The problem is that I want to re-render(update state) only if some condition in my state is happened and not in every resize event..
I try first with simple  implementation :

```
const useScreenDimensions = () => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerHeight);
  const [sizeGroup, setSizeGroup]useState(getSizeGroup(window.innerWidth));

 useEffect(() => {
  const updateDimensions = () => {
   if (getSizeGroup() !== sizeGroup) {
    setSizeGroup(getSizeGroup(width));
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  }
};

  window.addEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
  }, [sizeGroup, width]);

 return { height, width };

}
```

The problem with this approach is that the effect calls every time , I want that the effect will call just once without dependencies (sizeGroup, width) because I don't want to register the event every time there is a change in screen width/size group(window.addEventListener).

So, I try with this approach with **UseCallBack** , but also here my 'useEffect' function called many times every time there is any change in the state..

```
//useState same as before..
const updateDimensions = useCallback(() => {
  if (getSizeGroup(window.innerWidth) !== sizeGroup) {
  setSizeGroup(getSizeGroup(width));
  setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  setWidth(window.innerWidth);
}
}, [sizeGroup, width]);

useEffect(() => {
 window.addEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
 return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
}, [updateDimensions]);

....
return { height, width };
```

The question is what the correct and effective way for my purposes? I want just "register" the event once, and **update the my state only when my state variable is true** and not every time the width or something else get updated..

I know that when you set empty array as second argument to 'UseEffect' it's run only once but in my case I want that the register of my event listener run once and on resize I will update the state only if some condition is true

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call loading function with React useEffect only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once)

Comment: @HenryMueller it's not duplicate . I know that when you set empty array as second argument to 'UseEffect' it's run only once but in my case I want that the register of my eventlistner run once and on resize I will update the state only if some condition is true...

Answer (score 1):

use 2 different useEffect

first one for register event.So below code will run at the time of componentDidMount.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
}, []);
```

second useEffect to run based on state change.

```
useEffect(() => {
   updateDimensions();
   return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', updateDimensions);
}, [sizeGroup, width])


const updateDimensions = useCallback(() => {
 setSizeGroup(getSizeGroup(width));
 setHeight(window.innerHeight);
 setWidth(window.innerWidth);     
}
```

I'm not sure **useCallback** function need to use or not. And I've not tested this code.

Comment: Tnx, I try that but in this case eslint plugin 'force' me to set 'updateDimensions' function as dependency to the first 'useEffect' function , then what happend it's called every time there is a change in the state.. he want that dependency because in updateDimensions func I check some condition if to update state or not (sizegroup- you don't check that so maybe in your case eslint will not force you to set the func as dependency )

Comment: if you're passing [sizeGroup, width] to useEffect then you don't need to check condition. react hooks figure-out for you that when I need to run this function. so no need to if else condition.

Comment: So if sizeGroup and/or width will change only at that time updateDimensions function will call otherwise it'll not call.

Comment: if eslint force you to set updateDimensions as a dependency then in first useEffect add updateDimensions();

Comment: But I don't want to update my height and width(in state) in every resize event,it's all the point. In your code every resize event when screen width change also my state change , that what I try to avoid from him..that my state width/height will change only if sizegroup changed...

Comment: then use [sizeGroup] instead of [sizeGroup, width]

Comment: But I want to update my width also when sizegroup changed, and then when I add setWidth I have to set dependency of width...same loop ):

Comment: setters have a functional form `setWidth(oldWidth => newWidth)` to be able to remove the dependency on `width`...

Comment: I still not understand how it solve my problem. For my check (group) you still have here dependency if the width has been changed or not.. and then again the useEffect force you to set func as dependency and call many times .. @Aprillion

Comment: I think I just give up on 'group' under state and create function that calculate me the group by old width and new width  like @Aprillion write , then I can set new width to state only if group are different. I don't see another way to think how can I update my width without dependency on group...