# Simple counter doesn't stop incrementing inside functional component with useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks

I trying to use rxjs inside a functional component's useEffect Hook.

I believe useEffect can be used just like componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

```
 const Counter = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({counter: 0});
  useEffect(() => {
    subscriber.subscribe((value) => {
        let { counter } = state;
        counter += value;
        setState({ counter });
    });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Counter: {state.counter}</span>
      <Crementer />
    </div>
  );
```

The subscriber is a simple rxjs subject

```
const subscriber = new BehaviorSubject(0);
```

There's also a component to increment / decrement the counter

```
const Crementer = () => {
  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={() => subscriber.next(1)}>+</button>
      <button onClick={() => subscriber.next(-1)}>-</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

(I tried counterService.send(1) as well)

The problem is as soon as I click + or - the counter increments or decrements continuously.

You can see the behavior here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9auz4d

Maybe because useEffect runs also on update? It will probably work in a class component with a componentDidMount() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are invoked on every update: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#explanation-why-effects-run-on-each-update

So you could store the subscription returned form `subscribe` call and then keep it in another `useState`. On every effect invocation you'd just check whether it's set or not. Btw, you should also return a teardown function from this effect so that's where you'd need the subscription as well.

Or eventually you can use the second parameter to `useEffect` to run it just once ([How to call loading function with React useEffect only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once)):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = observable.subscribe((value) => {
    let { counter } = state;
    counter += value;
    setState({ counter });
  });

  return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

Comment: but it executes once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9auz4d?file=Counter.js, class components are just a lot easier and cleaner. Thanks for your explanation.