# RXJS - throttleTime not throttle

Tags: javascript, rxjs, throttling, debouncing

I have a simple click event with `React` function `component` and I try to throttle with `RxJS` `throttleTime`. Every click I `throttle` in `500ms` but it seems like throttle never work at all, but when I use debounce it works.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { throttleTime, debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

const subject = new Subject();

function Button() {
  const btn = useRef();
  const [clickCount, updateClick] = useState(0);
  const [debounceCount, updateDebounced] = useState(0);
  const [throttleCount, updateThrottled] = useState(0);
  const onClicked = e => {
    updateClick(parseInt(e.target.value, 10) + 1);
    subject.next(parseInt(e.target.value, 10) + 1);
  };
  subject.pipe(debounceTime(500)).subscribe(d => updateDebounced(d));
  subject.pipe(throttleTime(400)).subscribe(d => updateThrottled(d));
  return (
    <div className="button">
      <button value={clickCount} ref={btn} onClick={onClicked}>
        CLICK
      </button>
      <div>Actual clicks: {clickCount}</div>
      <div>Debounced clicks: {debounceCount}</div>
      <div>Throttle click: {throttleCount}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the problem is each click `clickCount` and `throttleCount` increases at same time but `debounceCount` works as expected, it wait `500ms` and updates.

[working live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-kirch-r5cp7)

Answer (score 0):

The component function `Button()` is called on every state change so you're making a new subscription on every state change. That's why it appears like it doesn't work.

Instead the subscription should go into `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  subject.pipe(throttleTime(400)).subscribe(d => updateThrottled(d));
}, []);
```

Also see [How to call loading function with React useEffect only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once).