# Infinite loop when set with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

there is such a production in react. I want the user to delete posts that they have shared. I do this:

- When the user logs in, I keep the user id as a cookie.
- I get the user name of the user that is equivalent to the id in the database with the captured id - HaoAsk
- I check with the username of the user who shares the post with the username I received
- if it is equal, I allow the user with setOwner.

But it goes into an endless loop.

```
const user = response.data.filter((dataItem) => (dataItem._id === userid));

const userNickname = JSON.stringify(user.map((value) => { return value.nickName }))
const nickName = userNickname.slice(2, -2)

const deneme1 = posts.filter( (data) => (data.who === nickName))

deneme1 ? setOwner([{ who: nickName,  status: true}]) : setOwner([{ status: false }])

console.log(owner)
```

When I use the following code, everything I write with console.log enters an infinite loop. I couldn't figure it out.

```
deneme1 ? setOwner ([{who: nickName, status: true}]): setOwner ([{status: false}])
```

Thanks in advance, Yours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any functional component, you normally want to make sure you don't use `set` outside the event function.

In your case,

```
   const onClick = e => { 
     // safe to use set method
     setOwner()
   }

   return (
      <Component onClick={onClick} user={user} />
   )
```

Because everything inside a functional component is inside the render cycle. It'll run when `react` try to refresh the display. In your case you set a state variable which triggers the render and then set the variable and then the infinite circle :)

What this means is that you have to find out an event after you initialize your component. In your case, it's a bit tricky, because you want to call this event right away automatically for you.

Please refer to something like this, [How to call loading function with React useEffect only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once)