# Invalid hook calls in react.js application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Having this error when running the program:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a
>   function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same ap

```
import React,  { Component } from "react";
import {useEffect,useState}  from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 
const App = () => {
const APP_ID = "";
const APP_KEY = "";
const exapmle = "https://api.edamam.com/search? 
q=chicken&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}";
  useEffect(()=>{
  console.log("effect has been");
  }); 

const [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);
return (
<div>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
  <form classname="search-form">
    <input classname="search_bar" type="text"></input>
    <button classname="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  <h1 onClick = {()=> setCounter(counter+1)}> {counter}</h1>
</div>);};
export default App();
```

Comment: Added code formatting and fixed minor grammar to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try `export default App` instead of `export default App()`.

I made a few other tweaks you can [test in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-curran-u2ydy?fontsize=14), namely:

- Using backticks to [embed template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in `example`
- [Limiting `useEffect` to a single execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once) by adding a second argument of `[]`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const APP_ID = '';
  const APP_KEY = '';
  const example = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=chicken&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect will run once if I pass it a second argument of []');
    console.log(example);
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <form className='search-form'>
        <input className='search_bar' type='text'></input>
        <button className='search-button' type='submit'>
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      <h1 onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}> {counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```