# How to add local storage to persist dark mode theme in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, themes, gatsby, react-context

I've tried everything to add local storage to persist theme. Any ideas on how to implement with the existing code? I get a mix of conflicting themes upon first rendering. I tried implementing local storage when setting theme.

```
const setTheme = type => {
  localStorage.setItem("theme", setState({ ...state, theme: type === "dark" ? theme.light : theme.dark })
}
    
const initState = {
  theme: localStorage.getItem("theme"),
  setTheme: setTheme,
}
    
const [state, setState] = useState(initState)
```

**ThemeProvider.js**

```
    
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
      theme: {
      
      },
      setTheme: () => {},
    })
    
export const ThemeContextProvider = props => {
      const theme = {
        light: {
          
        },
        dark: {
         
        },
      }
    
      const setTheme = type => {
        setState({ ...state, theme: type === "dark" ? theme.light : theme.dark })
      }
    
      const initState = {
        theme: theme.light,
        setTheme: setTheme,
      }
    
      const [state, setState] = useState(initState)
    
      return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={state}>
          {props.children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not make sense to me:

```
const setTheme = type => {
  localStorage.setItem("theme", setState({ ...state, theme: type === "dark" ? theme.light : theme.dark })
}
```

You want to set an item in localstorage but instead you are setting React state in the setItem function?

Two things to note:

- do not set the React state inside the localStorage.setItem function
- you can only save stringified values in localStorage. You cannot save a JavaScript object without turning it into a json string.

This is correct:

```
const setTheme = type => {
  localStorage.setItem("theme", state.theme }); // only save the theme value "dark" or "light" as a string
}
```

You need to trigger setting the state according to the values in localStorage or in initialState. Use `useffect` for this. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once) tells you how.