# Why this code is causing infinite loop to happen?

Tags: reactjs

Here is the code to initialize `categoryArray`. I want to run the `useEffect` only if the `categoryArray` data changes.

```
const [categoryArray, setCategoryArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/user/category')
            .then(response => {
                
                if (categoryArray !== response.data.category) {
               
                    setCategoryArray(response.data.category);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })

    }, [categoryArray])
```

I tried to apply a conditional statement to `setCategoryArray` only if there is some change but somehow that conditional statement is not working properly and an infinite loop is happening.

Could you please guide me on where I am getting wrong, also let me know if more information is required.

Comment: `[]==[]` is false, newly created array never equal anything, so `categoryArray !== response.data.category` always true,  so changed->effect->ajax->set->changed....

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of a `useEffect` marks on what value changes the `useEffect` should be triggered again.

Since you're setting `categoryArray` with the value of the `axios` call, but also configured the `useEffect` to be triggered when that variable changes, it will trigger again and again.

---

You probably can just remove the `[categoryArray]` so the `useEffect` is [only triggered once on the initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53120972/how-to-call-loading-function-with-react-useeffect-only-once).

Answer (score 0):

as can be seen in your code you have categoryArray in dependency array , and inside useEffect callback you are updating it,which cause it to generate infinite loop,if you need to load data only one time you just need to remove it from dependency,like

```
useEffect(() => {

    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/user/category')
        .then(response => {
            
            //if (categoryArray !== response.data.category) {
           
                setCategoryArray(response.data.category);
            //}
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

}, [])
```

or you can inside callback make sure that api call only executed if categoryArray.length==0,like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(categoryArray.length>0)return;
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/user/category')
        .then(response => {
            
            //if (categoryArray !== response.data.category) {
           
                setCategoryArray(response.data.category);
            //}
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })

}, [categoryArray])
```

this way it will only make api call when array is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/user/category')
            .then(response => {
                
                console.log("array: "+ response.data.category);
                
                if (JSON.stringify(categoryArray) !== JSON.stringify(response.data.category)) {
                    
                    setCategoryArray(response.data.category);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })

   })
```

By changing `if (categoryArray !== response.data.category)` to this `if (JSON.stringify(categoryArray) !== JSON.stringify(response.data.category))` and by removing `[categoryArray]` from `useEffect(()=>{.............},[categoryArray])` my code started to work fine and the infinite loops were handled by the conditional statement.

In my previous code, I found that even though `categoryArray` and `response.data.category` had the same value the code inside the conditional block was not executing so I searched different methods to compare arrays in javascript then I came across `JSON.stringify()`.

I didn't come across a proper explanation on why only `===` didn't work when comparing arrays in my case. If someone knows a reason why `JSON.stringify()` worked then please write the explanation so that it could be helpful to others.