# why the react hook setState always execute twice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I clicked the button div, and the console printed

```
click
111
setState
111
setState
```

why the setState always execute twice
This is my code

```
function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  console.log('111');
  return (
    <div>
      {num}
      <div onClick={ () => {
        console.log('click');
        setNum( num => {
          console.log('setState');
          return num + 1;
        })
      }}>button</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my function being called twice in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819162/why-is-my-function-being-called-twice-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

in `index.js` `remove` this `<React.StrictMode> </ React.StrictMode>` and u will see it rendering only once.

Answer (score -1):

But does **num** after click equals to 2 or 1 ?

Maybe this form will work better?

```
function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  console.log('111');
  return (
    <div>
      {num}
      <div onClick={ () => {
        console.log('click');
        setNum(num + 1)
      }}>button</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Also maybe try to use **button** for clicking, instead of **div**?