# API getting called twice in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend

My API is getting called twice on browser page reload as checked in the console. Can you please suggest. I am using axios to call the API in React.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from "react"

import {Container,Row,Col} from "reactstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import './App.css';

import Axios from "axios";
import MyCard from "./MyCard";

function App() {

  const[details,setDetails]=useState({});

  const fetchDetails=async ()=>{
    const {data}=await Axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/");
    console.log("RESPONSE:",data);
    const details=data.results[0];
    setDetails(details)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetchDetails();
  },[])

  return (
    <Container fluid className="p-4 bg-primary App">
      <Row>
        <Col md={4} className="offset-md-4 mt-4">
          <MyCard details={details}/>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my function being called twice in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819162/why-is-my-function-being-called-twice-in-react)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Answer (score 26):

**Fixed 1**

This only happens in dev mode. Going live will solve your problem.

**Fixed 2**

Removing strict mode will solve your problem.

**For Example**

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**To**

```
root.render(
    <App />
);
```

Comment: Removing StrictMode is the last thing to do. For a more detailed answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react

Answer (score 8):

The cause of the issue is in the development of react 18 with strict mode, the `useEffect` will be `mounted` -> `unmounted` -> `mounted`, which call the API twice.

### SOLUTION

You need to clean up `requests` or `events` when the component `unmounted`

### For API requests

you need to use `AbortController`, to `abort` the request after the component `unmounted` on the `return` callback.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const abortController = new AbortController();
  const result = await axios.get("/api/path", {
    signal: abortController.signal
  });

  return () => {
    abortController.abort()
  }
}, [])
```

### For DOM events

You should have a reference to the handler function and use `removeEventListener` on the `return` callback

```
useEffect(() => {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    // ...code
  }
  
  element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler)

  return () => {
    element.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler)
  }
}, [])
```

### FOR UNCLEANABLE EFFECTS

You can use `useRef`

```
const shouldLog = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
  if (shouldLog.current) {
    shouldLog.current = false;
    console.log('logged');
  }
}, [])
```