React component initially mounting and unmount the component then after it mounting what is the problem?
App component
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <FunctionalComp />
        <ClassComp />
    </div>
  );
}

Component 1
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const FunctionalComp = ({intial}) => {
    const [count,setCount]=useState(intial);
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(count!==intial){
            console.log('Functional Component did Update');
        }
    },[count])
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('Functional component mounted');
    },[])
    useEffect(()=>{
        return ()=>{
            console.log('Functional Component Will unmout');
        }
    })
  return (
    <div>
        <h1>FunctionalComp</h1>
        <h4>{count?count:0}</h4>
        <button onClick={()=>{setCount(count+1)}}>Count</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FunctionalComp

component 2
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class ClassComp extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            count:0
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('class Component did Mount ');
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log('Class component did update');
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        console.log('Class component will unmount');
    }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Class Component</h1>
            <h4>{this.state.count}</h4>
            <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({count:this.count+1})}}>count</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}


Output :
class Component did Mount
Functional component mounted
Class component will unmount
Functional Component Will unmout
class Component did Mount
Functional component mounted
Why its unmounting during the initial rendering
My expected output:
class Component did Mount
Functional component mounted
class Component did Mount
Functional component mounted

Almost certainly <StrictMode>, check where you're rendering App.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819162/why-is-my-function-being-called-twice-in-react and...

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>

</React.StrictMode>
); this is index.js i already use the strictmode

Right. It's because you use React's StrictMode that, in dev, your component is rendered twice. See the documentation I linked above.
